# How to destroy just the specific powerup I hit, not all of them?

Tags: unity, c#, physics, collider

Creating a game for a computer science class - basically I have a player (cop) who will collide with donuts. When the player collides with a Donut, I want the speed to increase by 0.5 each time. Here is the current code involving the collision (applied to the player object):

```
 private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Landmine"))
    {
        speed = speed - 0.5f;
        
        
    }
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Donut"))
    {
        speed = speed + 0.5f;
        Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("Donut"));
        
        
    }
```

The speed is working, but when the player collides with the Prefab tagged with "Donut", all the other donut objects also get destroyed. I just want to be able to individually destroy each Donut object, is there a way I can do this? I tried making the Donut game object into a prefab but it doesn't change anything since the collision script relies on the tag of the gameobject and not the gameobject itself. The donuts are duplicated objects of the first prefab.

[image]

Comment: Do not use screenshots for code, use the code block. And your collision.gameObject is already the donut you want to destroy, no need to search for it again. Just `Destroy(collision.gameObject)` should do the trick

Comment: @Zibelas Will do. That was indeed the solution, thanks so much!

Comment: You can write it yourself as an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line: `Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("Donut"));` says "search the entire scene (slow) for the first object that has the tag 'Donut', and destroy that".

But in this collision handler, you don't want to destroy just *any* old donut, and usually not specifically the *first* donut in scene search order. You want to destroy *the specific donut you hit*. Fortunately, that one's already stored in a variable - you used it to check if you hit a donut in the first place!

```
if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Donut"))
{
    speed = speed + 0.5f;
    Destroy(collision.gameObject);
}
```

Also, you'll probably want to use trigger collider for the donuts, and detect collisions with `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)` instead - that way you won't get any collision resolution impulses modifying the movement of your car. Trigger colliders *detect* and *report* overlaps, without pushing the colliders apart or acting like a solid barrier.

In fact, I'd rewrite this without two tag checks, and use the same script for both donuts and landmines:

```
public class SpeedChangePowerup : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speedChange;
    public bool destroyOnCollect;
    public Transform destructionEffectPrefab;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        if (!other.TryGetComponent(out PlayerCar car)) return;

        car.speed += speedChange;

        if (destroyOnCollect) {
            Instantiate(destructionEffectPrefab, 
                        transform.position,
                        Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Your donut is then just a prefab with a `SpeedChangePowerup` component that has `speedChange = 0.5` set in the inspector. Your landmine is one with `speedChange = -0.5`. And the car script doesn't need a collision handler with branches for each type of powerup, improving modularity and reducing bloat as you add other types of powerups and effects.